# passing array object to action class in struts2

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have a jsp page. In jsp page i have array of objects say history. In the jquery, i have got the index.Now i want to pass history[index] object to the action class in struts2. Here is the code which i have tried but it is showing error.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
     var rateDialog = $("#rateDialog").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         minHeight:250,
            width: 400,
            height: 265,  
         open: function( event, ui ) {
             $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
             $('#reviewArea').val('');
             }
         });

         $(".rate").on("click", function() {
             // Display the dialog
             rateDialog.dialog("open");
             alert( $(this).attr("id") );
             var index = $(this).attr("id");
             alert("${history.get(index)}");
         });
 });
 $("#submit").click(function(e) {
 $("#showDialogMessage").hide();
  var xmlhttp;
     $("#submit").prop('disabled',true);
     alert("called");
        var url="rate?object="+${history.get(index)};
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                document.getElementById("showPasswordMessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                $("#showPasswordMessage").show();
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
 });
});
```

Comment: What is the error ? Is it on the browser or server side ?

Comment: This is the error SyntaxError: illegal character
 
rl="rate?object="+com.markEffy.aggregator.TransactionDetails@6e0bbea6;

Comment: where is this error? browser or at server? Update your question with complete information.

Comment: You cannot pass whole object (at least not w/o some additional code). Pass uid of the object and retrieve it in the controller.

Comment: @AleksandrM Definitely Sir! But i just wanted to ask you.. is it a nice idea to keep the entire list of history object in the session and then i can pass the index to the action class. Based on the index i can retrieve the required object from the history list (i.e history[index]) which is stored in the session.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var url="rate?object="+${history.get(index)};
```

This is not a java question, this is javascript. 
The above line is the culprit

```
${history.get(index)}
```

is jsp code executing on the server and it fetches an object. What is printed is the toString() representation of the object (com.markEffy.aggregator.TransactionDetails@6e0bbea6). You probably should be accessing a property on the object

```
${history.get(index).someProperty}
```

Comment: Sir i tried. In the action class it is giving null. Here is my code var url="rate?index="+index+"&rating="+rating+"&review="+review+"&transactionId"+ ${history.get(index).transactionId};  and in action class getter and setter for transactionId